# Looking for a scifi movie probably 80's

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

In the movie a spaceship and crew have come across a stone that is pulling them towards a planet. When they get there, they find a shepherd boy  that falls into a earthquake ravine and sacrifices himself.  Then they see that he has become a council member of the universe.

Comment: You tagged "TV", but then stated it as a movie. Did you watch it as a TV film? When did you watch it? Cable? Satellite? Which country? Did you see the whole thing?